# Firefox not rendering <tr> rounded border, despite computed border-radius value

Tags: html, css

I am trying to round the bottom left corner of the bottom left cell of a table by 14px. I am able to do so for all browsers, except Firefox.

In Firefox the `<td>` cell is rounding, but the `<tr>` beneath it is overflowing, and I cannot manipulate it's border in any way unlike other browsers. Despite this, the computed value for the `<tr>` element suggests the border-radius is 14px, but it's appearance is that no border-radius is applied.

HTML

```
<table role="grid">
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr role="row" data-uid="da94159d-dc21-4a3c-88f1-5fde7cb5736c">
<td role="gridcell" class="round-grid-corner"><span>Add Section</span></td>
<td role="gridcell">24/01/2001</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.round-grid-corner{  
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px; 
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px; 
}
```

I have tried the following, with nothing happening.

- Adding background-clip:padding-box;
- Adding border radius to all elements
- Adding border-collapse: separate

Colouring the background-color of the `<tr>` is not an option as the table as it cuts off the table border.

Comment: `<tr>` is a virtual element, to wrap the cells of a row, no more purposes for that. You can stylize some properties, but not all of them. Other browsers maybe are making propietary things to achieve that. But the normal behaviour of a `<tr>` is for wrap the cells, no more. However, the code you share is working well with the border radius in the `<td>`. Please, explain better what you need because your code works. https://jsfiddle.net/7vu0ay9j/

Comment: Rows (`<tr>`) don't have borders, per se. It's the cells (`<td>`) elements that you want to apply border styling to, but not all CSS properties are applicable to all elements and I suspect that cells are one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the rounding to the table and the TDs. This is working for me in FF.

**Example:**

**HTML**

```
<table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Born</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>DeMarcus Cousins</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>6'11"</td>
            <td>08-13-1990</td>
            <td>$4,917,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Isaiah Thomas</td>
            <td>PG</td>
            <td>5'9"</td>
            <td>02-07-1989</td>
            <td>$473,604</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ben McLemore</td>
            <td>SG</td>
            <td>6'5"</td>
            <td>02-11-1993</td>
            <td>$2,895,960</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Marcus Thornton</td>
            <td>SG</td>
            <td>6'4"</td>
            <td>05-05-1987</td>
            <td>$7,000,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jason Thompson</td>
            <td>PF</td>
            <td>6'11"</td>
            <td>06-21-1986</td>
            <td>$3,001,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.zui-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table-rounded {
    border: none;
}
.zui-table-rounded thead th {
    background-color: #CFAD70;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    color: #333;
}
.zui-table-rounded thead th:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.zui-table-rounded thead th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.zui-table-rounded tbody td {
    border: none;
    border-top: solid 1px #957030;
    background-color: #EED592;
}
.zui-table-rounded tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.zui-table-rounded tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zinoui/3LfE2/)

Comment: Thanks, works like a dream. Strange that this only occurs in Firefox, but can see why they intending for you to be unable to modify <tr> in that way

Comment: According to the spec - rounding is not a property of table rows. It is likely that Firefox stuck to the spec and the other folks extended the spec. Maybe someday we will get to a point where all the browser developers would just stick to the specs.